# Layout small always opened after choose any device in Graphical Layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm desperate. I have a SIMPLE hello world app, with a wizard empty activity and two layouts:

res/layout/activity_main.xml
res/layout-small/activity_main.xml

activity_main.xml content is the same in both files:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FF0000"
android:padding="10dp"
android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I open layout/activity_main.xml first it's ok, graphical layout loads layout ok, but if I choose for example device Generic->3.7" WVGA (it's not small) in device list graphical layout manager open layout-small/activity_main.xml and if I try to change device to any I get this console log:

```
[2014-07-03 20:50:39 - prueba_layout] 'default' is not a best match for any device/locale combination.
[2014-07-03 20:50:39 - prueba_layout] Displaying it with ', , Locale Language ___Region __, Left To Right, sw320dp, w320dp, h480dp, Normal Screen, Short screen aspect ratio, Portrait Orientation, Normal, Day time, Medium Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Hidden keyboard, Qwerty keyboard, Hidden navigation, No navigation, Screen resolution 480x320, API Level 19'
```

I have tried Project->Clean & restart eclipse but does not work. Also I have reinstalled Eclipse and ADT plugin fully and problem still continues. Finnaly I tried remove all build path content to force eclipse rebuild but does not work either.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Providing Resources documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html):

> **Note:** Using a size qualifier does not imply that the resources are only for screens of that size. If you do not provide alternative resources with qualifiers that better match the current device configuration, the system may use whichever resources are the [best match](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch).

The limits of small, normal, large, and xlarge size qualifiers are *minimums* (see [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range)), and the minimum density for the small qualifier is 426dp x 320dp.

The `layout` directory is the fallback directory if no other directories are a better match. Since `layout-small` matches any screen size larger than 426dp x 320dp, the vast majority of devices on the market will match and use this directory instead.

**The solution**

There are a few ways to approach this. The easiest is probably to just copy the resources from `layout` and put them in `layout-normal` so that everything larger than "small" gets the "normal" resources.

You could also put the normal assets in a `layout-normal` folder, put the small assets in the `layout` folder, and nix the `layout-small` directory entirely.

You should also be aware that as of Android 3.2 (API level 13), use of the small/normal/large/etc. size groups is deprecated. Instead, you should be using screen width qualifiers, which not only provide more granularity but also make it more obvious that those qualifiers designate *minimums*, not an absolute match.

For more information on using the screen size qualifiers, see [Declaring Tablet Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts). Even though you aren't necessarily targeting tablets, the information is still relevant.

Comment: Ok but when i run app in emulator res/layout/activity_main.xml is shown in the same device which graphical layout load layou-small, why?

Comment: The best way to know for sure which layout will be loaded in the real world is to try it on an actual device. Sometimes an emulator or the IDE's layout editor will do strange things, and without knowing a lot more about your specific app and environment, it is difficult to troubleshoot the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: The app is a simple Hello world created with the wizard.